# Visual Studio 2013 debug puzzle C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, xdebug

Here's some pretty simple code, no?

```
strcpy (string2, string1);
int ipt, ipt2;
ipt2 = 0;
if (...)
    ipt = strFind(string1, ",");
```

Stepping through these statements in debug the watch view insists that "identifier "ipt" is undefined" even after stepping over the last statement shown.

The code worked perfectly well in VC6, why is ipt undefined in the 2013 version?

Comment: What do u mean by undefined?... In my VS 2013 Auto watch, Local watch and Watch1(if i add it there) it shows up... What exactly is it, you're doing?

Comment: I set a breakpoint on the strcpy statement then stepped line by line through the code. I added ipt to a watch list but it appeared with a small red circle and white cross saying "undefined". (I'm using the free Communities edition, which used to be Express, if that makes a difference).

Comment: @Incubbus OK I found the problem. I had to switch off all code optimization and then the variable showed up as expected.